# Create implicit conversion rule for custom data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, implicit-conversion, user-defined-types

I am writing a load of SQL to output .xml files for our customers. They prefer to have "Y" or "N" in BIT columns, rather than 1 or 0. We have a lot of BIT columns all over the place and I need to write `CASE WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END` more times than I have had hot dinners, to convert the data.

In a sense, that's fine and I should just get on with it and stop moaning, but I couldn't help wondering... If I created a custom datatype from a CHAR(1) base, which only allowed "Y" or "N" values, could I somehow make a rule for implicit conversion so that the machine will do the conversion for me reliably - converting 1 to "Y" and 0 to "N" every time?

I realise that there are other possibilities for achieving the same thing (using a .xsd to convert after the event to have Y/N instead of 1/0 for instance), but I'm interested in adding the custom type and the rule - is it possible and would it be sensible?

Comment: The T-SQL conversion mechanism isn't extensible in any way. This applies even to CLR data types (if you went that far); they convert only from/to binary, string or XML data, not `BIT`. What you want would be most proficiently done with a view; creating the view to transform all `BIT` columns could be done programmatically. In fact, I recommend spending your time on writing code to automate this tripe so you have more available for hot dinners (not involving tripe); `sys.columns` is your friend.

Comment: You mistake the *data type* for the *display string*. If your customers want boolean values to appear as localized letters, use the appropriate format on the client. The client knows if the boolean should appear as `T/F`, `Y/N`, `O/N` or `Σ/Λ`

Comment: XML already has a boolean type. XML is meant to be self-documenting and machine-readable. By replacing the built-in type with custom strings you break that and prevent other programs from using the data without parsing. Does your target schema use a different type for boolean perhaps?

Comment: you hvn't mention how many proc are there ?how many tables ?it is not justfied to change boolean to char.But a ascript can be written to alter all table and add extra column char(1),it all depend upon after analysis of everything.if using  .xsd solve your problem with least effort and code then go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is - AFAIK - no way to get your hands onto these internal processes.

From your question I take, that you are writing an XML file, so I assume, that you want the written letter in your XML files for better human readability? If so, better try to convince your people, that there's nothing wrong with `0` and `1`.

But you might save some typing:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WriteBit(@b BIT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
 AS BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
    SELECT CASE @b WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
                   WHEN 0 THEN 'N'
                   ELSE NULL END
    ); 
 END;
 GO

DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeInt INT, SomeBit BIT);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (0,0)
,(1,1);

SELECT SomeInt,dbo.WriteBit(SomeBit) AS SomeBitChar FROM @mockup;

SELECT SomeInt,dbo.WriteBit(SomeBit) AS SomeBitChar 
FROM @mockup
FOR XML PATH('test'),ROOT('root');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.WriteBit;
GO
```

The result in XML

```
<root>
  <test>
    <SomeInt>0</SomeInt>
    <SomeBitChar>N</SomeBitChar>
  </test>
  <test>
    <SomeInt>1</SomeInt>
    <SomeBitChar>Y</SomeBitChar>
  </test>
</root>
```

Comment: It would be far better to leave formatting to the client applications. Even if one created a proper Boolean SQLCLR type, formatting it to localized string is a job for the *client*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, that's why I wrote *try to convince your people, that there's nothing wrong with 0 and 1*. I assume, that the XML's consumer has got problems reading this (e.g. VBA takes `-1` as `true` ...). A written `true` or `y` might be less erronous. We don't know...

Comment: Didn't notice that. Even so,  XML does have a boolean data type. Using `Y/N` would defeat the purpose of using XML in the first place. It would no longer be self-documenting. if the target schema has a custom type that uses `Y/N` among others, it would make sense to serialize bits to that type.

Comment: I agree wie don't know, but it sounds as if there's a misinterpreted requirement here.

Comment: I was interested in the possibility as much as anything else and I see now that there is no possibility, but I see your point about keeping everything tied down in development and only changing values either at the last moment according to the client's wishes, or letting the client do the conversion. Marking the response as the answer for the first two paragraphs.

Comment: Requisite warning: [scalar-valued UDFs are performance traps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx). In this case everything is probably OK since we're exporting data (which is usually a perfectly sequential operation).

Comment: @JeroenMostert so true... I was waiting for this comment... ;-D

Comment: @Shnugo: I haven't yet written up boilerplate for this, but I might. Complete with a link to something like [this Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273443/). Here's to the next 10 years...